# Read through JSON number array using javascript loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting, date

I`m trying to write a loop that will read through a nested number array.

The JSON file that I`m reading goes like this. each number key represents event dates. 
[json reference for startdate and end date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpDve.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpDve.png)

I have below javascript code that reads per var i = 1 or j = 1. 
I`d like to read through entire nested number from dates and store them somewhere.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $.getJSON('http://app.toronto.ca/cc_sr_v1_app/data/edc_eventcal_APR?limit=500', function (data) {
    var data = data;
    var i = 2;
    var obj = data[i].calEvent;  
    var bingname = obj.eventName;
    var j = 1;
    var startdate = obj.dates[j].startDateTime;
    var time = new Date(startdate);
    var starttime = time.getFullYear()+'-' + (time.getMonth()+1) + '-'+time.getDate();
    var name = JSON.stringify(bingname);   

    document.getElementById("bingname").innerHTML = name;


    document.getElementById("bingtime").innerHTML = starttime;


    var name = firebase.database().ref("/bing").set({
      EventName : name,
      EventStart : starttime
    });

  });
});
```

Now, I should use something of incremental loop for var j. But I'm not sure how. 
The problem for me is that json retrieved in obj.dates[j] doesn't seem like an array. I can't seem to read it as list of numbers to read through. Help is much appreciated.

If anyone can even sort this nearest to furthest from today's date that'd be Einstein:)

Comment: `obj.dates[j]` is an object.  You can iterate the array with a `for` loop.  These are both really basic javascript concepts that you should learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get an array of objects, that includes a callEvent object that has a dates property which is an array with objects with the property's startDateTime and endDateTime. 
It will look like following:

```
[
    {
      callEvent: {
        dates: [
          {startDateTime: '', endDateTime: ''},
          // more objects with start- and endDateTime
        ]
      }
    },
    // more callEvent objects..
]
```

Now your code should loop through the array to get all callEvent objects and loop through all dates objects inside each callEvent.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON('http://app.toronto.ca/cc_sr_v1_app/data/edc_eventcal_APR?limit=500', function (array) {

        // loop through all elements in the array
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            // loop through all dates inside the array 
            for (var j = 0; j < array[i].calEvent.dates.length; j++) {
                console.log(array[i].callEvent.dates[j].startDateTime)
                console.log(array[i].callEvent.dates[j].endDateTime)
            }
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't `data[i]` be `array[i]` and `array[i].dates` be `data[i].callEvent.dates`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the dates are valid JSON ([JSON Validator](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)), then you should just be able to get the data and loop through it:

```
for (var i=0;i<data.length;++i) {
  console.log(data[i].startDateTime);
  console.log(data[i].endDateTime);
}
```

Comment: JSON doesn't specify a format for dates, however ECMAScript provides a [*Date.prototype.toJSON*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-date.prototype.tojson) method for use by [*JSON.stringify*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-json.stringify).